# Alternative of column -t command in python?

Tags: python

Is there any command/function in python like we have in linux to format the column using `column -t`

cat file.txt

```
99912  ram                  8sdfg  61888
99908  ram                  8sdfg  62144
99901  shyam             8sdfg  9072
99902  shyam             8sdfg  5840
99905  ramshyam  8sdfg  6576
99910  ramshyam  8sdfg  2480
```

```
cat file.txt |column -t
99912  ram       8sdfg  61888
99908  ram       8sdfg  62144
99901  shyam     8sdfg  9072
99902  shyam     8sdfg  5840
99905  ramshyam  8sdfg  6576
99910  ramshyam  8sdfg  2480
```

How to achieve same output in Python, any suggestion please?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not. you can, however, utilize the `column` program in your python script if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an overkill, but you can try pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter=r"\s+", header=None)
print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))

#99912      ram 8sdfg 61888
#99908      ram 8sdfg 62144
#99901    shyam 8sdfg  9072
#99902    shyam 8sdfg  5840
#99905 ramshyam 8sdfg  6576
#99910 ramshyam 8sdfg  2480
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatted printing.

```py
message = "some text or other"

print( f"A {message:>40}" )
print( f"B {message:>35}" )
print( f"C {message:>30}" )
print( f"D {message:>25}" )
```